# Why it happens - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error caused by Model.clean()?

Tags: python, django

I have a clean method that gives me RelatedObjectDoesNotExist  error in my model file

```
@with_author 
class BOMVersion(models.Model): 
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    material =  models.ForeignKey(Material)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    abovequantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    belowquantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)  





    def clean(self):
        model = self.__class__
        if model.objects.filter(material=self.material, is_default=True).count()  > 1:

            raise ValidationError('Material {} has a defaul value already'.format(self.material))
```

UPDATE:
Traceback

```
> Traceback: File
> "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> in get_response
>   132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py"
> in _wrapped_view
>   22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\item\views\viewsbomversion.py" in
> bomversion_new
>   68.         if form.is_valid(): File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in
> is_valid
>   184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in
> errors
>   176.             self.full_clean() File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in
> full_clean
>   394.         self._post_clean() File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in
> _post_clean
>   430.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False) File
> "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py"
> in full_clean
>   1132.             self.clean() File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\item\models.py" in clean
>   673.         if model.objects.filter(material=self.material, is_default=True).count()  > 1: File
> "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py"
> in __get__
>   608.                 "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
> 
> Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at
> /item/bomversion/new/1/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/material/material_bomversion_details/1/
> Exception Value: BOMVersion has no material.
```

It looks like material is not visible from within clean method.
It is ok if I remove the material from the validation and leave only is_default field.

I am clueless why.....

UPDATE:

the problem is probably that material value is not coming from the form but gets populated in the view

```
 if form.is_valid():
            bomversion= form.save(commit=False)
            bomversion.creation_time = timezone.now()
            bomversion.material = material
            bomversion.save()
```

Comment: what's is_default? It'd be better if you posted the whole error here maybe. Also, you can use `exists()` instead of `count() > 1`

Comment: The default is BooleanField I use count since I allow only one default for each material so this validation checks it .

Comment: @dietbacon `exists()` is not valid here, since the author needs to know if there are *more than* 1, not if it has one or more

Comment: @trinchet oh yeah, you're right.

Comment: Just a hunch, but could it be that you're calling `self.material` on an instance of BOMVersion that doesn't have a material object associated with it (i.e. that foreign key is not pointing at anything)?

Comment: I think you are in right direction. I receive material value not from the form but I populate it in the view. 
 clean() method is  probably triggered before it gets assigned with value in the view. 
Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `is_valid()` on the form it's calling the model's clean method. Since you're only assigning material after calling `is_valid()`, when `self.material` is called, `self.material` is not associated with any `Material`object.

Instead of checking that on the clean method, since you already have the Material instance when you're saving the form, you could raise an exception before calling `is_valid()`. Remove the check from clean and then add:

```
if model.objects.filter(material=material, is_default=True).count()  > 1:
    raise ValidationError('Material {} has a default value already'.format(material))
```

before calling `is_clean()` or somewhere before saving the instance.